# What is, or should be, the Magic Resistance required to resist the Fuse spell?

Tags: spells, anima-beyond-fantasy, resistance

The Fuse spell states, in its Added Effects block, “+5 to the MR and +5 to the maximum Presence affected”.  However, nowhere in the text I have in front of me (taken from the basic sourcebook in English) is the base MR stated - only the base Presence.  The text is included below.

> Unites two beings in a single body, creating a new individual who possesses the characteristics and abilities of both. The caster designates which capacities prevail, selecting those that he is interested in from each. If the spell joins a fighter and a psychic, for example, the resulting individual could have the fighting ability of the warrior, the mental powers of the mentalist, and the highest Secondary Abilities of each one. Control of the resulting united body falls to whichever of the two wins an Opposed Check of Willpower, although some characteristics typical of the other personality can be retained. The original bodies remain in the state they were in before the fusion and so, when the spell lapses, return to the state and condition they were in before it was cast. The death of the joint entity causes the death of both original people. The total Presence of both originals cannot be more than 80. It is also possible to Fuse an individual with objects, in which case the GM can award the result the advantages and abilities he considers appropriate.

What is the base MR of the Fuse spell?  If no canonical source exists, what *should* the base MR be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want canonical sources there are two ways to handle this:

1. In the Core Exxet the Fuse spell was assigned an MR for each level it can be cast at:

> Base: MR80 / Max Presence 80.
>   Intermediate: MR120 / Max Presence 100.
>   Advanced: MR140 / Max Presence 150.
>   Arcane: MR180 / Max Presence 200.

2. If you want to use the original magic system:

   - The reason Fuse doesn't have one listed in the Core Book is that it is considered a 'beneficial' spell, which are not commonly resisted as they usually are a form of enhancement.  However the rules do account for if someone wants to voluntarily resist an 'effect' type spell like this.  It is listed under the **Common Spell Features** as the **Base Magic Resistance**: *(pg. 115)*.  This rule stipulates that these spells can be treated as having Base MR120.

Comment: Yeah.  There are certain bits of the spell that give it an offensive use...especially in combination with other spells.